# unix program copy to dest, but if the file is present in the dest, I should copy in dest/duplicate

Tags: shell, unix

I have problem on my shell program (the code is below), I should copy file from directory sorg to dest, but if the file is present in the dest, I should copy in dest / duplicate, the program does not work.

```
#!/bin/sh

sorg=$1
dest=$2
path=$3

cd $sorg

for i in *.jpg
do
    #controllo se il file esiste nella destinazione
    if test -f "$dest/$i"
     then
        #il file esiste
         mv $i "$dest/duplicati"
    else
       #il file non esiste
       mv $i "$dest" 
    fi 

done
```

Comment: what is the problem? please post errors, help us to help you...

Comment: The program doesn't copy file from folder sorg to dest

Comment: did you create the `duplicati` directory? else it will move all files to the same file called `duplicati` (too bad for your files...)

Comment: Yes the directory duplicati is create

Comment: what are the values of the arguments? show us how you invoke your script (in the question please), and the execution trace. We can't see that from here :)

Answer (score 1):

It's bad practice to change directories from within a shell. If your input arguments are not absolute paths, then your script does not work at all.

Example with `input` and `output` in the current directory:

```
sorg=input
dest=output
```

Plus, you have to protect all operations with quotes or else it will fail if filenames have space characters in it (which is the case, according to our discussion)

First, your script performs a `cd input`. Since `dest` is relative, it now points to `input/output` which does not exist.

Either, convert your arguments as absolute (not very good), or modify to avoid having to change directory (the best option)

I have changed your code so changing directory is no longer needed. The difficulty consists in computing the basename of the input file to compute destination names.

I also added the directory creation since it would be disastrous if the `duplicati` directory did not exist: all duplicates would be moved to the same file `duplicati` !

(comments in english are from me :))

```
#!/bin/sh

sorg=$1
dest=$2
# this is not used, commenting out!
# path=$3

if [ ! -d "$dest/duplicati" ] ; then
   mkdir "$dest/duplicati"
   if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
      # cannot create duplicate dir: bail out
      exit 1
   fi
fi

# scan jpg files from source directory
for fpi in $sorg/*.jpg
do
    # compute basename from full source path
    i=$(basename "$fpi")
    #controllo se il file esiste nella destinazione
    if test -f "$dest/$i"
     then
        #il file esiste    
         echo duplicate: moving $fpi to $dest/duplicati/$i         
         mv "$fpi" "$dest/duplicati/$i"
    else
       #il file non esiste
        echo moving $fpi to "$dest/$i"      
       mv "$fpi" "$dest/$i" 
    fi 

done
```

Comment: i have try with your code, but the shell print this message: usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: can you edit your question to show your arguments? is there space chars in your paths?

Comment: there aren't  space chars in my path

Comment: ??? I have added `echo` commands before the `mv` commands. Can you take the last version and try it, post the results.

Comment: the result is below

Comment: I have edited my answer to add quotes. A quick test on my bash showed it was OK: `for` echoes the proper paths. Your traces suggest that adding the quotes will work.